# Table and \tikzexternalize

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-external, tabu

It might not be a usual thing to do but I need to put some tikz pictures in a Table with externalization. I did

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
%\tikzexternaldisable
%
\begin{filecontents}{A.tikz}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{B.tikz}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

%
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabu}{cc}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{A}
    \input{A.tikz}
    &
    \tikzsetnextfilename{B}
    \input{B.tikz}    
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It works if I disable tikzexternal. Any suggestion?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: It works for me!

Comment: Thanks, I screw up my example. The problem seems persist when I use tabu and tabularx. I updated the example above.

Answer (score 2):

This is a 'feature' of `tabu`. If you trace the code, you find that it deliberately disables writing (amongst other things) to do trial typesetting runs without any real result from write operations. That includes disabling `\write18`, which is needed by TikZ to do externalisation. As such, '`tabu` is out' is the best I can say: ask a separate question showing what you want to do and we'll try to find a `tabu`-free way.

---

For the technically-minded, the problem comes from

```
\def\tabu@nowrite #1#{{\afterassignment}\toks@}
```

which is `\let` as a replacement for the `\write` primitive for trial typesetting runs. As you can see, this simply grabs the argument to `\write` into a throw-away toks.